# Escaping spaces in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cherrypy

I have the following Apache mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:4321/$1 [proxy]
```

This works great; Apache forwards all requests to the CherryPy server I have running on the same machine.

Unfortunately, I'm having some problems with paths which have a space.  If I make a request for `/Sites/some%20site/image.png` then Apache makes a request to CherryPy for `/Sites/some site/image.png` which messes up CherryPy.

Is there a way to specify in my RewriteRule that I'd like to re-escape spaces in the URL before forwarding the request to CherryPy?

EDIT: I found a reference to [something that might help](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6064), but I went ahead and ducked the problem by replacing the spaces with underscores and having CherryPy do a conversion before serving the files.

I'd still like to know a better solution if anyone has one; unfortunately I'm on a deadline and don't have time to muck around with this myself at the moment.  I may return to this later and post further updates when I find the time.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact rule you have? That'd be the behavior if you used the [NE] flag. You might have stumbled upon a bug, what's your apache version and platform?

Comment: This is the exact rule; I copy/pasted it out of my .htaccess file.  I'm using Apache 2.2.9 on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Try enabling the rewritelog in rewriteloglevel 9 and check if there's a clue, because this is weird

Comment: You can get Apache to re-encode spaces manually with the `B` flag. Something like `[B=\ \,BNP]` works (`BNP` makes Apache use `%20` instead of `+`). This is available on Apache 2.4.26+ (flags reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModRewrite#Bewaretheencodingbug for the best known solution.